# R: generate means and SD table from some columns of a table by group

Tags: r

My apologies if this question has already been answered but I can't find it.

I have a table in R: (see below example copied from txt, the actual table has more data and NA)
I need to compute the mean and sd from column c, e, and f by the group in column b

I can calculate the mean and sd separate by group for all of the separate e.g.

```
mean(c[b == 1], na.rm=TRUE) 
var(e[b == 2], na.rm=TRUE)
```

I can also calculate the mean and SD for all the columns and generate a table with the results

```
library(data.table)
new <- data.table(project2016)

wide <- setnames(new[, sapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean = round(mean(x), 3), sd = round(sd(x), 3))), by = b], c("b", sapply(names(new)[-1], paste0, c(".mean", ".SD"))))
wide
```

But I am not able to do it for only the needed colums and separated by group.

Thx in advance,
Nimby

```
  "id" "a" "b" "c" "d"    "e"     "f"  "g"
    1   78  2   83  4   2.53    1.07    3
    2   72  2   117 4   2.50    1.16    2
    3   72  2   132 4   2.43    1.13    2
    4   73  2   102 4   2.48    .81     2
    5   73  2   114 4   2.33    1.13    2
    6   73  2   88  43  2.13    .84     2
    7   65  2   213 4   2.55    1.26    1
    8   68  2   153 4   2.45    1.23    1
```

Comment: It is helpful to include some data where from which we can reproduce the problem. As far as I can see, all rows have b == 2 here. It's best if we can copy and paste something straight into the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)


# Some reproducible data

d <- matrix(c(1, 78, 2, 83, 4, 2.53, 1.07, 3, 2, 72, 2, 117, 4, 2.50, 1.16, 2, 3, 72, 2, 132, 4, 2.43, 1.13, 2, 4, 73, 2, 102, 4, 2.48, .81, 2, 5, 73, 2, 114, 4, 2.33, 1.13, 2, 6, 73, 2, 88, 43, 2.13, .84, 2, 7, 65, 2, 213, 4, 2.55, 1.26, 1, 8, 68, 2, 153, 4, 2.45, 1.23, 1),
      ncol = 8, byrow = TRUE) %>% 
        as.data.frame

names(d) <- c("id", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")

# Your data only included one group in column b
d$b[5:8] <- 1

# Calc mean and sd for the 3 columns, grouped by b
d %>%
    group_by(b) %>%
    summarise(mean_c = mean(c), sd_c = sd(c), 
                        mean_e = mean(e), sd_e = sd(e), 
                        mean_f = mean(f), sd_f = sd(f))

d
```

This yields

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
      b mean_c     sd_c mean_e       sd_e mean_f      sd_f
  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1  142.0 54.35071  2.365 0.18064699 1.1150 0.1915724
2     2  108.5 20.95233  2.485 0.04203173 1.0425 0.1594522
```

There'll also be non `dplyr` ways to do it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.

To my regret I wasn't able to get it to work in R. I get the next message; Error in summarise_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : argument ".data" is missing, with no default

In the meanwhile I figured out how to split my data and I used: library(fBasics) basicStats(b_c)[c("nobs","NA", "Mean", "SE Mean", "Stdev", "Variance", "1. Quartile", "3. Quartile" ),]

So I even got some extra statistics on the go ;-) It is ofcourse data per group element and not all in one table but it is enough for now.